# VS says "Too few arguments...", but other compilers give me a correct output?

Tags: c++, recursion, edit-distance

I am doing edit-distance between two strings. It uses recursive function. Online compilers are compiling the code and giving me an output of 3, which is correct, but visual studio says "Too few argument in the function call" Can someone else please help out?

I have looked at other threads, and they genuinely missing arguments, but I do not, yet VS is flagging my recursive call

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int min(int x, int y, int z)
{
return min(min(x, y), z); // here VS flags error
}

int editDist(string str1, string str2, int m, int n)
{

if (m == 0) return n;


if (n == 0) return m;

if (str1[m - 1] == str2[n - 1])
    return editDist(str1, str2, m - 1, n - 1);

return 1 + min(editDist(str1, str2, m, n - 1),    
    editDist(str1, str2, m - 1, n),   
    editDist(str1, str2, m - 1, n - 1)
);
}


int main()
{
string str1 = "sunday";
string str2 = "saturday";

cout << editDist(str1, str2, str1.length(), str2.length());

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;` and use `std::min`. This is a perfect example for why you shouldn't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh My God!! It worked. Never using `using namespace std` again. Thank you friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `std::min`, you need to use `#include <algorithm>`.

If it works on some compilers, that's because got lucky and some of the headers you use include `<algorithm>` (maybe indirectly).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to your function name matching with the standard minimum function `std::min`

```
int min(int x, int y, int z){
    return min(min(x, y), z); // the compiler is getting confused over whether to 
    //call std::min which takes two parameters or user-defined min which 
    //takes three parameters
    }
```

Change your function name and it should work fine.

Comment: Or better yet, remove `using namespace std;`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. I just did it to X_Y_Z, still says, "Too Few Arguments for function call" And X_Y_Z does not take two arguments.

Comment: @Ayxan, just tried that too. `using std::cout` and `using std::string`. Same error as above.